# R to salesforce connector

Tags: trigger

I have written a code in R (the statistical language.) I want Salesforce to call this code periodically (maybe once a day.) I want my SFDC data to run through my R script and then give an output that automatically uploads back into SFDC. Does anyone know how to set up this process?

I found somewhere how to automatically call SFDC data into R, however, I want this process to be automated such that the output is automatically uploaded back into SFDC periodically.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

As far as automating the process goes, I see two ways of making this work:

1. On a local machine or server, schedule the R code to run periodically (using cron).  The code will pull data from salesforce and then push back up the results.
2. Put the R code on a server and expose it to Salesforce via an webservice. Salesforce would call the service, passing in the data to process and the service would return the output.

If you go with Option 1, there a several ways to easily get the data back into salesforce:

1. Use the [partner/enterprise API](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/apex_api.pdf) (soap)
2. Use the [rest API](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/REST_API)
3. Write your own custom [rest](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST) or [soap](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_web_services_methods.htm) web-service

If the output is ready to go directly into objects then option 1 or 2 are best.  If you need to do additional logic and create multiple objects in a transactional setting then option 3 is the way to go.

I have very limited experience in R, but I would think a REST API would be easier to work with.  A quick google return a [article](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/vignettes/json-apis.html) that might be helpful.  However, there does appear to be a library [SSOAP](http://www.omegahat.org/SSOAP/) to consume Soap WSDL within R.